# How to use OpenCV's cv::Mat& to calculate "Coefficient of Variation"?

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, coefficients, opencv-mat

I'm trying to build an iOS to detect image changes from Camera.

OpenCV's iOS SDK kindly provides a delegate method passing cv::Mat&.

How can I calculate **"Coefficient of Variation"** using cv::Mat& ?

Should I look for a solution from combining multiple methods using cv::Mat& ?

Being a novice to OpenCV, I'll be immensely grateful to receive any hint.

Comment: Mat is just a matrix, it's up to you to fill it with meaningful values. What's the coefficient of variation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indeed use the various `Mat` methods provided by the opencv, Some required for calculating `Coefficient of Variation` are :

[meanStdDev](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#meanstddev) : This will return you `mean` intensity value of the input mat and another `Mat` of the same size as the input `Mat` containing the values of deviation from the mean value.

[mean](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mean) You may also like to find out the mean value of the output `Mat`.

Also depending upon the various mathematical operations, you should have a look at the [available methods](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#operations-on-arrays) and try to get the desired results using that methods only

**Never** try to iterate over the whole `Mat` and then perform computations, it is lot more slower than the inbuilt methods on `Mat`.